# Check if number contains all digits

Tags: haskell

What is the efficient way to check, whether a number contains all digits in Haskell? Modifying lists is terribly inefficient, so keeping a list of number of occurences of each digit is not okay. You could just keep 10 Bool variables in recursion, in which you go through list of digits of your number, but that seems too ugly.

Comment: You mean check whether every character is a digit? Or whether all possible digits 0-9 appear at least once? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason that a list is terribly inefficient for your purpose. You can use a set to keep track of the digits you have seen.

```
import Data.List 
import qualified Data.Set as S

digits = foldr S.insert S.empty . unfoldr go where 
  go 0 = Nothing 
  go n = let (a,b) = n `divMod` 10 in Just (b,a) 

hasAll10Digits = (== (S.fromList [0..9])) . digits
```

`insert` for `Data.Set` is O(log n), but the set you are inserting into will never have more than 10 elements, so these insertions are essentially constant time.

Answer (score 6):

I have made much faster solution than [user2407038's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29106115/2541573).

```
import Data.Bits
import Data.Char
import Data.List

hasAll10Digits = any (==1023) . scanl setBit (0::Int) . map digitToInt . show
```

In `ghci`, it runs hasAll10Digits (12^223451) in just 0.03 seconds.

In comparison, user2407038's code runs in about 11 seconds.

Comment: An equally fast implementation is `import qualified Data.Set as S`; `hasAll10Digits = any ((== 10) . S.size) . scanl (flip S.insert) S.empty . show`.  It just uses the same algorithm with a different intermediate structure to store the result.  This also works with `Data.Map` in approximately the same amount of time.

Comment: @bheklilr, yes, you could do that, but No_signal's solution can reasonably be expected to run far faster, as long as the lists fuse away properly (which they might in GHC 7.10 but won't in GHC 7.8). Doing this somewhat by hand seems quite reasonable, swapping out the `any` and the `scanl` for a higher-order `foldr`. Or you could go really by hand and drop the `show`, which seems likely to help matters anyway. Be sure to exclude the RTS startup time when comparing.

Comment: @dfeuer, compiled with -O2 they are equal also `map digitToInt . show` is faster for large numbers then anything i could find

Comment: What GHC version? `scanl` was not very smart about list fusion until 7.10.... Did you try `-fllvm` to speed up the by-hand conversion? GHC's native code generator is pretty stupid about division by known divisors—I'm pretty sure it only handles powers of two.

Comment: when i say large numbers i mean integers. `quotRem` is faster for `Int` but you can't beat show for getting the digits of a large `integer` even with `-fllvm`

Answer (score 3):

This is based on No_signal's [excellent approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29106655/1477667), but makes a few little optimizations to run without allocating any unnecessary structures. To make this fast, compile with `-fllvm`—GHC's native code generator doesn't do a good job of optimizing division by known divisors.

```
hasAllDigits :: Int -> Bool
hasAllDigits = go 0x3FF where
 go !_set 0 = False
 go set n = case (clearBit set r) of
    0    -> True
    set' -> go set' q
   where
     (q,r) = n `quotRem` 10
```